# No database selected error after explicit declaration_base

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm having this issue, where sqlalchemy does not recognize the database, even though it is declared with `declarative_base`. After trying to run a simple query of `session.query(AppGeofencing).all()` I get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1046, 'No database selected')`.

The table is declared as

```py
Base = declarative_base()
AppBase = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema='app'))

class AppGeofencing(AppBase):

    __tablename__ = 'geofencing'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(45))
    polygon = Column(Geometry('POLYGON'))

    def __init__(self, name=None, polygon=None):
        self.name = name
        self.polygon = polygon
```

The case is only with this table, because I have also done similarly for other tables, and they work just fine.

After enabling the logging for sqlalchemy I can see that is does indeed create the correct query

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT app.geofencing.id AS app_geofencing_id, app.geofencing.name AS app_geofencing_name, ST_AsEWKB(app.geofencing.polygon) AS app_geofencing_polygon 
FROM app.geofencing
```

but somehow it cannot determine the database to use?
Does anyone have any idea, what could cause such issue?

Comment: Your SQLAlchemy connection URL needs to specify a default database. It doesn't necessarily have to be the `app` database but it does need to exist on the server to which you are connecting.

Comment: @GordThompson ok, but what happens if I want to query from different database, while maintaining the same URL connection? Will it handle it automatically?

Comment: If your ORM class uses a declarative base that points to a specific schema (a.k.a. "database" in MySQL) then yes, the resulting queries will hit that database.